# Problems with user-theme gsettings schemas

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gsettings

Recently I started to learn shell scripting. I've planned to create a script to change the GTK and Shell theme of my Pop_OS as an exercise. I was first learning and testing the commands individually, just to see if it will behave like a need it to.
I successfully changed the icon and gtk theme, but when I was changing the Gnome shell theme, the following output was presented:

```
No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme”
```

It's strange because I have the User Theme extension enabled. I also did the following command, and nothing changed.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
```

Does someone know what's happening, or can give me a suggestion of what to do?

Answer (score 3):

I also just ran into this problem. I'm not entirely sure what went wrong, but it seems the schema file was never properly installed.

To fix this, you'll need to get your hands on a copy of the schema file: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme.gschema.xml`. You can get the file from the program's source, which the gitlab link is given on the [extension's page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

Once you have the file, copy it into the schemas directory at `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schema`. And once inside that directory, compile the schema file with the others. (eg `sudo glib-compile-schemas .`).

*Then* you can finally set the value. :)

Comment: Worked great for me! Thank you!